# Swagger cannot parse YAML: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token :"

Tags: node.js, yaml, swagger

I tried to follow this guide: https://blog.cloudboost.io/adding-swagger-to-existing-node-js-project-92a6624b855b. I changed this line to use YAML:

```
swaggerDocument = require('./swagger.yml');
```

The example from the Swagger editor does not work. http://editor.swagger.io/

```
tags:
  - name: "pet"
    description: "Everything about your Pets"
```

Gave this error:

```
  - name: "pet"                
        ^                      

SyntaxError: Unexpected token :
```

I tried to change the indentation but it didn't help. I looked at the specification but it says that is OK: https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html#id2761803

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to change it to

```
var swaggerUi = require('swagger-ui-express')
var fs = require('fs')
var jsyaml = require('js-yaml');
var spec = fs.readFileSync('swagger.yml', 'utf8');
var swaggerDocument = jsyaml.safeLoad(spec);
```

And move `app/swagger.yml` to the project root directory. `fs.readFileSync()` cannot understand `./swagger.yml` the way `require()` does.